# Toggle multiple search areas and the handle icons

Tags: jquery, html

What I need this to do is toggle each search area when the `<h2>` is clicked.

I need it to also toggle the class icon-minus and icon plus on the `<h2> <span>` element. (This isn't shown on my fiddle as it needs the fonts installed.)

On load it should show only show the first search area and the rest are hidden (display:none).

It must also have the ability to toggle the current search area and icon.

I've had a lame attempt [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbUbg/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.  You just needed to add a [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) so the current div isn't hidden with the others

```
$('.s-container h2').on('click', function () {
  var $el = $(this);
  var div = $el.next('.s-area');
  $('.s-area').not(div).hide(); // hide all but the current one that is toggling
  div.slideToggle('fast',function(){ 
      // add correct class accordingly to the h2 elemeents
      $('.s-container h2').attr('class',function(){
            return $(this).next('.s-area').is(':visible') ? 'icon-minus' : 'icon-plus';
      });
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3KESK/